# No tf function for applying transformations?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm seeing this design strategy in the online course I'm doing:

```
translation = tf.transformations.translation_from_matrix(T)
rotation = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_matrix(T)
t.transform.translation.x = translation[0]
t.transform.translation.y = translation[1]
t.transform.translation.z = translation[2]
t.transform.rotation.x = rotation[0]
t.transform.rotation.y = rotation[1]
t.transform.rotation.z = rotation[2]
t.transform.rotation.w = rotation[3]
```

Is there a function for doing something like:

```
t.apply_translation(translation)
t.apply_rotation(rotation)
```

or

```
t.apply_transformation(translation=translation, rotation=rotation)
```

I think it would make for more readable code, and be faster to write. If there is a function like that, what is it? If not, why not?

Thanks!
TT

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262050/no-tf-function-for-applying-transformations?/) by [TristanTrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30442/tristantrim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-05-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the snippet you posted it seems you are basically populating a `geometry_msgs/TransformStamped` message from the matrix conversions (done via `transformations.py`).  ROS messages don't have apply methods like you have asked for but are often accompanied by conversion utilities/packages such as [tf_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf_conversions) or [eigen_conversions](http://wiki.ros.org/eigen_conversions?distro=kinetic). For your particular case you might find something in [posemath.py](https://github.com/ros/geometry/blob/indigo-devel/tf_conversions/src/tf_conversions/posemath.py) useful either directly or for some ideas on how to implement your own helpers/conversions.

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TristanTrim](https://answers.ros.org/users/30442/tristantrim/) on 2017-05-18**:
Ahh, yes, this makes sense. I'm guessing then that what you're publishing as a message will vary enough that it makes sense to always include some kind of conversion utility, rather than just having a built in conversion utility.